# Problems after updating packages with Magento connect manager

Tags: magento-1.9, varnish, magento-connect-manager

I initially only went to Magento connect manager to update M2E Pro but noticed there were some other updates so I went ahead and committed to these. I then had a 504 gateway error, refreshing the page I was left with errors which related to an extension called Turpentine - Varnish Cache. The front and backend were down. I went through many options to try and fix the problem such as commenting out the complier (it was already disabled anyway), deleted files from /var/cache etc still to no avail.

I then found out there were no files in the extension's location so I transferred them over from my backup and both front and backend came back! Now, the front end has completely changed, it looks like it's reverted back to the base or default template whereas it should point to /rwd.

Seeing as the problem seemed to have started from the varnish extension, I went to check if I could enable / disable it manually or via the admin panel. But the extension .xml file was not there, so I then transferred it from our backup, it now shows but makes no difference. I can't see the varnish options I used to have on the cache management page which tells me I'll need to reinstall it?

Trying to uninstall / reinstall via connect manager, I get a permission denied error, I then tried using custom permissions changing both folder  & files to 777, still don't work.

I am completely lost on what to do, any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try downloading the extension using http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php and manually install it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I've installed it manually and i can see the extension installed as the settings are showing on the cache management page but the problem still remains of the front end showing an old template.

Comment: Do a diff of your backup vs current site to see if there are any layout.xml missing. Also check your admin design setting.

Comment: Theres no difference, and on admin design the only field thats being used is Current Package Name which shows rwd, as it should. The others are blank. Perhaps another extension which had a failed update caused this?

Comment: Just to add, we use a data content provider who also host our site - i took this up with them and they told me because i requested gzip compression to be turned on, they also compressed some files manually, when i went to update the extensions and got the 504 gateway error, its because of the compressed files. Can this be true?